# Python - Excel - Modify Specific Row Height with Openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, row, height, openpyxl

I need to format the height of 2 rows in an excel workbook using openpyxl.  There is only 1 sheet in the workbook.  I managed to figure something out for formatting the width of the columns, but I can't seem to figure out how to do the row height.

I need to format row 1's height to 130, and row 2's height to 25 - all else to remain the default 15.  This is the code I have for formatting the column width:

```
newFile = "MyWorkbook.xlsx"
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename = newFile)        
worksheet = wb.active
for column in ascii_uppercase:
    if (column=="A"):
        worksheet.column_dimensions[column].width = 37
    elif (column=="B"):
        worksheet.column_dimensions[column].width = 37
    elif (column=="C"):
        worksheet.column_dimensions[column].width = 37
    elif (column=="D"):
        worksheet.column_dimensions[column].width = 130
    else:
        worksheet.column_dimensions[column].width = 15
   
wb.save(newFile)
```

I tried to translate this to work for row height, but it didn't seem to work - any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
for row in ascii_uppercase:
    if (row=="1"):
        worksheet.row_dimensions[row].height = 130
    elif (row-=="2"):
        worksheet.row_dimensions[row].height = 25
    else:
        worksheet.row_dimensions[row].height = 15
```

Comment: The row keys should integers, not strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looping through `ascii_uppercase` and not finding the cases?

**UPDATE**

The `height` attribute expects integer values corresponding to the row numbers. You can try something like this:

```
for row in range(worksheet.max_row):
    if (row == 1):
        worksheet.row_dimensions[row].height = 130
    elif (row == 2):
        worksheet.row_dimensions[row].height = 25
    else:
        worksheet.row_dimensions[row].height = 15
```

Comment: What should I put there instead?

Comment: I've updated the answer with some suggestion.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works!  I'll look into studying & applying that.  Thanks again